# How to get parameters with add_filter with a static method?

Tags: oop

I use this add_filters to append some links to each comment:

```
add_filter('comment_text', array($this, 'printModerateLinks'));
```

How do I pass the other attributes in this static method to my method "printModerateLinks"? I need the comments object in "printModerateLinks".

Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consult the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_text) or source code to see how many arguments are passed to the filter. We can see it has 3 in total, and the comments object is the second one, so you'll need to have at least two.

Next, you'll want to declare the number of arguments to pass to the function you're hooking on, which is the 4th parameter of `add_action`/`add_filter`

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', array( $this, 'printModerateLinks' ), 10, 3 );
```

Lastly, make sure you add the parameters to your method that's being hooked on.

```
public function printModerateLinks( $comment_text, $comment, $args ) {
```

Now you can access the comment object with the `$comment` variable.